# Org-mode: force subheading to end and continue in parent heading

Tags: org-mode

Say I'm writing a text:

```
* Animals

There are many of them in the wild.

** Examples of animals :noexport:
- Dogs
- Fish
- Triceratops

# I'd like the subheading to end here!! Following sentence should belong to outer scope. 

Animals are not the same as plants.

* Plants

There are also many of them in the wild.
```

I'd like my subheading `Examples of animals` in the example above, to end after `- Triceratops`, and all further text to continue on the parent heading `Animals`. Currently, if I cycle visibility and hide `Examples of animals`, then all text below it will be hidden up entil the next heading.

**How can I force to prematurely end a headline?!**

If this functionality is not implemented in org-mode, **how can I insert structured text in the middle of a heading and selectively hide (org-cycle) it?**

Comment: Pretty sure you can't.

Comment: Any alternatives to insert structured text in the middle of a heading and selectively hide it? The solution need not consist of a subheading

Comment: An example block `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE...#+END_EXAMPLE` would seem more appropriate here.

Comment: Plain lists may also work (prefixed with dash). They're foldable, but are treated as plain text, so you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `org-mode` is strictly hierarchical.  Once you begin a headline at a certain level, nothing ends it except a new headline.  You can't return to the previous one.  If you want a certain chunk of text in the middle of a section to be set off and foldable you want a [block](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html#Literal-examples);  use either an example block or a source block (with `org` as the source language):

```
#+NAME: examples-of-animals
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
- test 1
- test 2
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

`EXAMPLE` blocks are exported literally.  If you want formatted export (and to control whether it exports at all) use a [source](http://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-source-code.html#Working-with-source-code) block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC org-mode :exports none
** Examples of animals
  - test 1
  - test 2
#+END_SRC
```

http://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-source-code.html#Working-with-source-code
In this case the `:exports none` option causes the block to not be exported, but it will be editable as normal `org-mode` text.

Answer (score 3):

That cannot be done: org-mode imposes a strictly hierarchical structure on the document. As a possible answer to your last question, you may be able to use inline tasks - see the [Org-mode FAQ](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#closing-outline-sections) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, but inline tasks do not selectively hide, i.e., they still glob the contents until the next heading comes around.

Comment: I think these are two *different* questions.  OP wants to insert some text belonging to the **parent node**; the example described in the linked page is to insert text belonging to the previous **sibling node** instead of the current one.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use an inline task for this. It is like a headline but usually 15stars deep. It is not part of the outline hierarchy.

Comment: I didn't know about inline tasks. They are cool but they still obey the org-mode structure, i.e., they'll still glob all content until the next heading comes around.

Comment: You need to add an END at end of a 15 star headline to make it like a drawer. See http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-inlinetask.el;hb=HEAD